# MySQL how can I search for media in virtual folders

Tags: php, mysql, search, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to figure out how to make a search engine for my media database.

The structure for the virtual folders is:

**table directories**

```
id name parent
```

The structure for the medias is:

**table medias**

```
id name parent
```

I'm using the following php function to list all my directories

```
function print_menu($id = 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT directories.id AS id, directories.name AS name, directories.parent AS parent, directories.icon AS icon FROM directories 
    WHERE directories.parent = '".$id."' GROUP BY directories.id ORDER BY directories.name ASC";
    $req = $cnx->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute();
    if ($req->rowCount()>0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while ($data=$req->fetch()) {
            echo "<li>".$data['name']."</li>";
            print_menu($data['id']);
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
 }
```

Now lets say I got the following folders

- Root

  - project 1

    - dir 1

      - subdir 1
      - subdir 2
      - subdir 3
    - dir 2

      - subdir 1
    - dir 3

      - subdir 1
      - subdir 2
  - project 2

    - dir 1

      - subdir 1
      - subdir 2
    - dir 2

      - subdir 1
      - subdir 2
      - subdir 3
    - dir 3

      - subdir 1
  - project 3

    - dir 1

      - subdir 1
    - dir 2

      - subdir 1
    - dir 3

      - subdir 1

And I want to search for medias named "%media_1%" in "project 1" including all its subfolders, how can I do that without making a query for each folder and subfolders? The level of subfolders can vary.

Comment: Unless you know a maximum depth, I am not sure it is possible without a different table structure.

Comment: Thats my fear, do you have any idea what table structure would do? Considering that I need something dynamic (moving folders around, renaming them, etc...)

Comment: How would you do that with a maximum depth? A join of each level?

Comment: Yes, a join of each level including the preceding levels, I'll put an example in answer form in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution, I'm using the function posted above to get the ids of all subdirectories for a given directory, lets say "project 1" has the ID 42 I'll use

```
$all_ids = array();
function print_menu($id = 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT directories.id AS id, directories.name AS name, directories.parent AS parent, directories.icon AS icon FROM directories 
    WHERE directories.parent = '".$id."' GROUP BY directories.id ORDER BY directories.name ASC";
    $req = $cnx->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute();
    if ($req->rowCount()>0) {
        while ($data=$req->fetch()) {
            $all_ids[] = $data['id'];
            print_menu($data['id']);
        }
    }
 }
all_ids[] = 42;
print_menu(42)
```

Then I'm just doing a request like

```
SELECT * FROM medias WHERE medias.parent IN (".implode(',', $all_ids).") AND medias.name LIKE '%media_1%'
```

The request will only search for media in "project 1" and its subdirectories, no matter how many levels

Comment: Unless I am missing something, that looks like it will only get the immediate subdirectories.

Comment: You're missing the call print_menu($data['id']); each time it finished with a directory it will call its subdirectory until there is none left.

Comment: Ah, I completely overlooked the recursion; I though the person that posted the question wanted to avoid multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

In general, with a "tree" table, to get a list of all descendants, and a known max depth you can construct a query like this:

```
SELECT layerN.ID
FROM theTable AS layer1
   INNER JOIN theTable AS layer2 
      ON layer1.id = layer2.parent_id 
      OR layer1.id = layer2.id
   INNER JOIN theTable AS layer3
      ON layer2.id = layer3.parent_id 
      OR layer2.id = layer3.id
   ...
   INNER JOIN theTable AS layerN
      ON `layerN-1`.id = layerN.parent_id 
      OR `layerN-1`.id = layerN.id
WHERE layer1.parent_id = [chosen_parent_node_id]
;
```

Without the additional "OR" clauses in the ON conditions, intermediate nodes would not be included.
If intermediate nodes are not desired and the "leaf" nodes are of varying depths, the `INNER JOIN`s will need to be `LEFT JOIN`s, and the `SELECT` field will be a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT IFNULL(layerN.id, IFNULL(`layerN-1`.id, IFNULL(....))) AS leafID
```

**Alternately**

You could have an additional table for summarizing total ancestry, the simplest version would have two fields `ancestor_id` and `descendant_id` (though you could include a "distance" as well). The biggest problem would be that it would need to be maintained through code of some form, triggers on the tree table would probably be the most effective and reliable method.

Comment: Can you please explain more about ancestor_id and descendant_id with Example ?

Comment: The basic idea is when a node is insert into the tree table, inserts could be into the "ancestry" table. One for the parent node (with distance of 1), and a copy of the parent's ancestors (with a distance + 1) (aka. `INSERT INTO ancestors(a_id, d_id, distance) SELECT a_id, [new_node_id], distance + 1 FROM ancestors WHERE d_id = [id_of_new_node's_parent]`). Obviously, on delete things would need to be updated as well.

Comment: I need to show n level tree , and wanted to make virtual directory tree.


CREATE TABLE directories
 (`id` int, `name` varchar(50), `parent_id` varchar(10))
;
 
INSERT INTO directories
 (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
 (1, 'root', ''),
 (2, 'SuperCat1', 1),
 (3, 'SuperCat2', 1),
 (4, 'Cat11', 2),
 (5, 'Cat12', 2),
 (6, 'Cat21', 3),
 (7, 'Cat22', 3),
 (8, 'Cat23', 3),
 (9, 'SubCat231', 8),
    (10, 'SubCat232', 8)
;

Comment: SELECT
b.name as layer2,
c.name as layer3,
d.name as layer4
FROM
directories a,
directories b,
directories c,
directories d
WHERE
(a.id = b.parent_id OR a.id = b.id) and
(b.id = c.parent_id or b.id = c.id)and 
(c.id = d.parent_id or c.id = d.id) and 
a.id = 1